# unable to give a path to DownloadManager

Tags: android, storage

i would download with DownloadManager a file in a specific directory. At the beginning of my app, i create (if doesn't exist) a folder:

```
if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        externalStorageWriteable = true;
        directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        directory = new File(directory_path);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
    }
```

if i check with a filemanager, folder it's available at /sdcard/folderName but if i print on logcat directory_path variable, i obtain

```
/storage/emulated/0/folderName
```

I try to download file by passing destination folder like

```
Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(directory_path));
request.setDestinationUri(destination);
//request is of type DownloadManager.Request
```

but when i check where file it's stored, my folder is empty and downloaded file is stored inside /sdcard/Download

Could someone tell me why and how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add .toString()

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
```